# OSClass:: AdSense code not saving

Tags: adsense, osclass

Can you help me to figure out where the AdSense code in OSCLASS saves. I have installed NextRevo theme.

When I am trying to add AdSense code in Theme settings then on clicking save button AdSense code doesn't save. It displays home page.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to ask the theme developer for that. You reach them [here](http://market.osclass.org/themes/general/next_131), check the 'Having a problem  ?' link.

There seems to exist a Adsense Plugin too (look [at the forums](http://forums.osclass.org/)) and [a video from the Osclass team on Youtube](http://osclass.org/tutorials/become-a-pro/how-to-add-adsense-to-your-site_73).